# How to update a subdocument (REF)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the method below to update all the fields in the "Producers" document.

```
exports.updateProducers = async (req, res) => {
    let obj = new Producers(req.body);
    await Producers.findOneAndUpdate({ "user.nome": "Naomi"}, obj, {upsert: true, new: true}, function (err) {
        (err ? res.status(400).send(err) : res.status(200).json(obj));
    });
}
```

This method works and normally updates all the "Producers" fields, however, I have a reference to the "User" document, done like this:

```
user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
```

In "Users", I have the "name" field. How can I add editing on users as well?

I'm currently getting this message:

> MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

**I appreciate if anyone can help me analyze what I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Friend  when you created the instance of product like you did with `obj`, you only created a temp instance and that instance was not saved into the database, so the used method to update, only needs a filter and the update, and a few optional parameters, so if you want to update from a property like name or something else, use this instead:

```
const resultOfUpdate = await Producers.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        "users.name": "Naomi"
    },
    obj,
    {
        upsert: true,
        new: true
    }
)
```

Use REST API approach to have a good understanding on how to update a document, for more details, check out these sources:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-findbyidandupdate-function/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm

Comment: {
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 66,
    "codeName": "ImmutableField",
    "name": "MongoError"
}

Comment: I am getting this information above. MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'